# Script Can't Open Document (Inaccessible, Please Try Again)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a copy of a document and populate it with data from a spreadsheet. I can successfully create the copy but the script can't seem to access it to edit its contents. Here's the code:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1mWFhZpZVJpYJleg9n5qq3tr7EHwUIlbM');
var copy = file.makeCopy('SKPembimbing_' + nim, folder).getId();
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy);
var body = doc.getBody();
```

It always gives me an error at the 3rd line when it tries to open the document for editing.

```
(Exception: Document is inaccessible. Please try again later.)
```

I saw another thread from last year with the same exact question but without a solution. I've been working all night trying to get this darn thing to work. Does it have to do with my scope? I'm running it on a trigger on edit.

Comment: `makeCopy` returns a File object. Can you not call `getBody()` on that, or does the same thing happen? in general, why are get its ID then immediately open it by that ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

The template document I was copying was a .docx file, NOT a Google Doc. The copied file was thus also a .docx file so was inaccessible from the DocumentApp. All I had to do was convert it to a Google Document.